# Density for the convolution of a probability measure and a gaussian distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification, density-function

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $(\mathbb R^d,\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d))$, and let $\xi_{1/k}$ denote the $d$-fold product of the Gaussian distribution with mean zero and variance $\frac{1}{k}$. Let $\varphi$ denote the characteristic function of $\mu$. Am trying to show that the convolution $\mu \ast \xi_{1/k}$ has a density $f$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda^d$, with

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^d}\int_{\mathbb R^d} \varphi(x) e^{-i\langle z,x \rangle}e^{-\frac{\|x\|^2}{2k}}\lambda^d(dx).$$

I did the following:

Let $A\in  \mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$ and let $g_{1/k}$ denote the density of $\xi_{1/k}$. We have

$$(\mu \ast \xi_{1/k})(A)=\int_{\mathbb R^d\times\mathbb R^d} 1_{\{x+y\in A\}}d(\mu \otimes \xi_{1/k})\overset{Tonelli}{=}\int_{\mathbb R^d}\int_{\mathbb R^d} 1_{\{x+y\in A\}}\xi_{1/k}(dy)\mu(dx)=\int_{\mathbb R^d}\int_{\mathbb R^d} 1_{\{x+y\in A\}}g_{1/k}(y)\lambda^d(dy)\mu(dx)$$

$$\overset{z=x+y}{=}\int_{\mathbb R^d}\int_{\mathbb R^d} 1_{\{z\in A\}}g_{1/k}(z-x)\lambda^d(dz)\mu(dx)\overset{Tonelli}{=}\int_{\mathbb R^d}\int_{\mathbb R^d} 1_{\{z\in A\}}g_{1/k}(z-x)\mu(dx)\lambda^d(dz)=\int_A \int_{\mathbb R^d} g_{1/k}(z-x)\mu(dx)\lambda^d(dz),$$

which shows that $f(z)=\int_{\mathbb R^d} g_{1/k}(z-x)\mu(dx)$ is a density for $\mu \ast \xi_{1/k}$ with respect to $\lambda^d$. Since $\xi_{1/k}$ is a $d$-fold product of $N(0,\frac{1}{k})$, we have

$$ g_{1/k}(y)=\bigg(\frac{k}{2\pi}\bigg)^{d/2}\exp \bigg\{{\frac{-k\|y\|^2}{2}}\bigg\}.$$

Now, if $\phi$ denotes the characteristic function of $\xi_{k}$, then  by using Fubini's theorem (complex case) and the known formula for the characteristic function of $N(0,k)$ we get

$$\phi(t)=\int_{\mathbb R^d}e^{i\langle t,y \rangle}\xi_k(dy)=\exp \bigg\{{\frac{-k\|t\|^2}{2}}\bigg\}.$$

Therefore, regarding $f(z)$ as a complex integral, we get

$$f(z)=\bigg(\frac{k}{2\pi}\bigg)^{d/2}\int_{\mathbb R^d} \int_{\mathbb R^d}e^{i\langle x-z,y \rangle}\xi_k(dy)\mu(dx).$$

Applying Fubini's theorem (complex case) once more, we obtain

$$f(z)=\bigg(\frac{k}{2\pi}\bigg)^{d/2}\int_{\mathbb R^d} \int_{\mathbb R^d}e^{i\langle x-z,y \rangle}\mu(dx)\xi_k(dy)=\bigg(\frac{k}{2\pi}\bigg)^{d/2}\int_{\mathbb R^d} \bigg[\int_{\mathbb R^d}  e^{i\langle x,y \rangle}\mu(dx)\bigg] e^{-i\langle z,y \rangle}\xi_k(dy)$$

$$=\bigg(\frac{k}{2\pi}\bigg)^{d/2}\int_{\mathbb R^d} \varphi(y)e^{-i\langle z,y \rangle}\xi_k(dy)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^d}\int_{\mathbb R^d} \varphi(y)e^{-i\langle z,y \rangle}\exp \bigg\{{\frac{-\|y\|^2}{2k}}\bigg\}\lambda^d(dy).$$

Is this correct? Thanks a lot for your comments/feedback.

Comment: your solution seems correct. I was just wondering why you want to have the density in terms of the Fourier transform of the conculution measures?

Comment: @OliverDiaz Yes this is because I want to  use this lemma to show that characteristic functions determine measures uniquely: if $\mu,\nu$ have the same characteristic functions, then $\mu \ast \xi_{1/k}=\nu \ast \xi_{1/k}$ for each $k$ (since they have the same densities). Since $\mu \ast \xi_{1/k} \Rightarrow \mu$ and $\nu \ast \xi_{1/k} \Rightarrow \nu$ as $k\to\infty$ (to be shown), it follows that $\mu=\nu$ by  uniqueness of weak convergence limits.

Comment: That is what I though. In any case, there is general procedure that may be of interest to you. I added it as an answer (by Community wiki).

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment, that I think fits better here:

In general, suppose $\mu$, $\nu$ are finite Borel measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and that $\nu\ll\lambda_n$ ($\lambda_n$ is Lebesgue's measure) and that $g=\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda_n}$.
Then $\int e^{-2\pi ix\cdot t}(\mu*\nu)(dx)=\widehat{\mu*\nu}(t)=\widehat{\mu}(t)\widehat{g}(t)$, where $\widehat{g}(t)=\int e^{-2\pi ix\cdot t}g(x)\,dx$ and $\widehat{\mu}(t)=\int e^{-2\pi ix\cdot t}\mu(dx)$.

From this equation, you can substitute $g$ for the density off a Gaussian (or any other density) to derive several identities.
On the other hand $\mu*\nu\ll\lambda_n$ and
$$f:=\frac{d\mu*\nu}{d\lambda_k}(x)=\int g(x-y)\mu(dy)$$
Hence $\widehat{f}=\widehat{\mu}\widehat{g}$.

If $\widehat{g}\in L_1$, then by Fourier's inversion formula
$ g(x)=\widehat{\widehat{g}}(-x)$ and so
$$f(y)=\int \Big(\int e^{2\pi iz\cdot(x-y)}\widehat{g}(z)\,dz\Big)\,\mu(dx)=\int e^{-2\pi iy\cdot z}\widehat{g}(z)\Big(\int e^{2\pi ix\cdot z}\mu(dx)\Big)\,dz$$

Comment: I have two questions: 1) Isn't $\frac{d\mu*\nu}{d\lambda_k}(x)=\int g(x-y)\mu(dy)$? 2) Isn't $\widehat{g}\in L_1$ a consequence of Fubini's theorem? The map $(x,y)\mapsto e^{-2\pi ix\cdot y}g(x)$ is jointly measurable and $\mu\otimes \nu$ integrable (since $\nu$ is finite), so Fubini should give  $t\mapsto \widehat{g}(t)$ $\lambda_n$-integrable no?

Comment: @Alphie: (1) was a typo, now corrected. (2) If $g\in L_1$,  then is is not necessarily true that $\widehat{g}\in L_1$. The argument you presented in not correct: $|e^{-2\pi ix\cdot y}g(x)|=|g(x)|$ so $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n}|e^{-2\pi ix\cdot y}g(x)|\,dx\,dy=\infty$

Comment: @Alphie: The Gaussian function $g(x)=e^{-|x|^2/2}$ happens to be one of many $L_1$ functions for which $\widehat{g}\in L_1$.

Comment: Ok thank you I see why my reasoning was incorrect. I believe in my proof this translates into $\phi(t)=\int_{\mathbb R^d}e^{i\langle t,y \rangle}\xi_k(dy)=\exp \bigg\{{\frac{-k\|t\|^2}{2}}\bigg\}$ being $\lambda_n$-integrable. So in fact the result holds more generally under the conditions you stated.

Comment: @Alphie: Since you are using a Gaussian in your argument, there is no problem with integrability. Other distributions will work too, in particular the Cauchy distribution. These to examples are standard in the harmonic analysis. The first is related to the wave equation *Gaussian kernel), the later to Laplace equation (Poisson kernel).